# Wordpress admin: set category from variable instead of checkbox

Tags: wordpress, submit, admin, categories, posts

The only way to set a category to a new post seems to be to select the appropriate one via a check-box before submitting it.
At best, you can set a *default* category as an option in case no box has been checked by the user.
This is really a problem for me as my admin menus are and have to be the categories themselves.

As I mentioned, in my WordPress admin I have a custom menu listing category names. Clicking on one leads directly to the generic "add a new post" page.
What makes it less generic is that I have inserted the category ID within this link, like this: "`wp-admin/post-new.php?cat=5`".

At this point,I would like not to check a category from a box before submitting the new post. Instead, I want WordPress to use the variable provided in the URL and submit the category ID accordingly when my new post is ready to be published.

Is it possible?
Which file would I have to edit in order to achieve this?
Any other idea that would lead to the same result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension that you will develop. It is better than trying to modify Wordpress core files.

I did something that may help you in one of mine. Using this :

```
if(is_admin()){
add_action('post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'plugin_add_custom_box');
}

function plugin_add_custom_box(){
?>
<div class="al2fb_post_submit">
<div class="misc-pub-section">
<?php
    echo '<input type="checkbox" id="plugin" name="plugin_action" value="1"/>';
    echo '<label for="plugin">';
    _e("Label", 'myplugin_textdomain');
    echo '</label> ';
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
```

This add a custom checkbox. Using the same name for the checkbox here than checkboxes already displayed by Wordpress and checking it analysing your URL, you will probably be able to store the category you want without modifying core files.